# Is it possible to use search on Google Maps v2?

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I couldn't find any related topics so i opened a new one.

What i want is to be able to search some words and let user go to this point.

Example: There is a map in a screen and there is a searchbar at top. Whenever the user writes as "London" the map should move to London.

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Isn't that what Google does?

Comment: Oh, sorry if I misspoken. I mean I want that option in my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to read about the [geocoder class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html)

[getFromLocationName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocationName%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) returns an ArrayList of [Address](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html)es. Each address contains the latitude and the longitude of the point.

Comment: Umm I have been searching about this and I don't think I got this. What i understand is geocoder is mostly about getting the address of selected point. What i want is to search an address and let the map to move to result point. So, please help me more about it

Comment: after you get the coordinates use maps api to interact with the map, more precisely move the camera. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views#the_camera_position Also check http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html for a good summary of what to do with maps